# Помогите, после функции c ttf2woff и ttf2woff2 не работает browserSync

Tags: gulp

```
let project_folder = "dist";
let source_folder = "#src";



var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
var del = require('del');
var group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries');
var clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var webp = require('gulp-webp');
var webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html');
var webpcss = require('gulp-webpcss');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
var svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite');
var ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff');
var ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2');


let path = {
  build: {
    html: project_folder + "/",
    css: project_folder + "/css/",
    js: project_folder + "/js/",
    img: project_folder + "/img/",
    fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
  },
  src: {
    html: [source_folder + "/*.html","!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"],
    css: [source_folder + "/css/*.scss","!" + source_folder + "/css/reset_css.scss"],
    js: source_folder + "/js/*.js",
    img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
    fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf",
  },
  watch: {
    html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
    css: source_folder + "/css/**/*.scss",
    js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
    img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
  },
  clean:"./" + project_folder + "/"

}



function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch([path.watch.html],html),
  gulp.watch([path.watch.css],css),
  gulp.watch([path.watch.js],js),
  gulp.watch([path.watch.img],img)
}



function clean(params) {
  return del(path.clean);
}



function browserSync() {
  return browsersync.init({
    server:{
      baseDir:'./' + project_folder + "/"
    },
    port:3000,
    notify:false
  });
}



function html() {
 return gulp.src(path.src.html)
 .pipe(fileinclude())
 .pipe(webphtml())
 .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
 .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}



function css() {
  return gulp.src(path.src.css)
  .pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: "expanded"
  }))
  .pipe(group_media())
  .pipe(autoprefixer({
    overrideBrowserslist: ['last 16 versions'],
    cascade:false
  }))
  .pipe(webpcss())
  .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
  .pipe(clean_css())
  .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
  .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
  .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}



function js() {
  return gulp.src(path.src.js)
  .pipe(fileinclude())
  .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
  .pipe(uglify({}))
  .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
  .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
  .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}



function img() {
  return gulp.src(path.src.img)
  .pipe(webp({
      quality: 70
  }))
  .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
  .pipe(src(path.src.img))
  .pipe(imagemin({
    progressive: true,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox:false}],
    interlaced: true,
    optimizationLevel: 3
  }))
  .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
  .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function fonts() {
   // src(path.src.fonts)
   //  .pipe(ttf2woff())
   //  .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
  return src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(ttf2woff2())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));

}


gulp.task('svgSprite', function () {
  return gulp.src([source_folder + '/iconsprite/*svg'])
  .pipe(svgSprite({
    made: {
      stack: {
        sprite: "../icons/icons.svg"
      }
    }
  })
)
  .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
});
gulp.task('default',gulp.parallel(gulp.series(clean,gulp.parallel(html,css,js,img,fonts)),watchFiles,browserSync));
```

Comment: Такая же беда. Как-то решили эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите fonts из параллельного выполнения задачи. Пускай отдельно выполняется. Должно заработать.